# Set interval on jQuery hoverIntent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-hover, hoverintent

I am using the jQuery hoverIntent plugin and I love it.  However, I am having trouble setting a custom interval.  My jQuery is:

```
   var hoverSetting = {
                            sensitivity: 4,
                            interval: 75,
                        };

                        navItem.hoverIntent(function(hoverSetting) {
                            if (searchIsVisible == false) {
                                overlay.delay( 500 ).css('display', 'block');
                                $(this).find('ul').toggleClass("active");
                                overlayIsVisible = true;
                            }
                        });
```

How can I make the interval at which hoverIntent works custom (I would like to slow it down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax instead:

```
var handleInOut = function(){
           if (searchIsVisible == false) {
                overlay.delay( 500 ).css('display', 'block');
                $(this).find('ul').toggleClass("active");
                overlayIsVisible = true;
            }       
       };

navItem.hoverIntent({
   over: handleInOut,
    out: handleInOut,
    sensitivity: 4,
    interval: 750
});
```

Comment: Sorry I missed a closing bracket.  Also apparent the `out` parameter needs to be defined as well.  Answer is updated.

Comment: Care to elaborate what "not working" means?  Getting a JS error?

Comment: I found a couple more hanging commas, try updated answer again.

Comment: I had to remove the comma after the bracket following 'true' and it is now working.  However the toggleClass on the ul is now not working.  It adds the class 'active' but does not remove it on mouseOut

Comment: In your question I didn't see any function regarding the mouseOut.  Whatever functionality you need during mouseOut, put that code inside the `out: function(){   }`.  Makes sense?

Comment: That does make sense, but it's not quite solving the problem.  Hate to be a pain.  But on my original hover, the ul had a toggleClass of active.  Now, it just remains active, even if I had a remove class in the 'out' portion of your code

Comment: Ok I see you were using the hoverInOut method.  I updated my answer to use the same function in both over and out handlers.